# EdmNavigationPropertyInfo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, metadata, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use OData v4 from the Webstack nightly builds for my web service. During the creation of the EDM model in an attempt to create the navigation properties I am instantiating the EdmNavigationPropertyInfo object. I am not sure what needs to be set on the DependentProperties and the PrincipalProperties.

Appreciate any help in pointing me to helpful documentation on using the odata v4 api's.

Comment: I'm currently struggling through this myself. This article may help somewhat: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/leohu/2013/11/04/typeless-entity-object-support-in-webapi/
Specifically, see the GetModel() method example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have clr types correspond to these EDM types? if yes, just try below code.

Assume the CLR types are:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public IList<Order> Orders{get;set;}
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public String Description{get;set;}
}
```

Then to get the Edm Model, you could use below code:

```
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
    builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
    builder.Namespace = typeof(Customer).Namespace;
    var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
    return edmModel;
}
```

The Orders will automatically become a navigation property of the Edm Customer type.

These samples may help you:https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/